# How to create a bookmark in a Word 2013 document using python?

Tags: python, ms-word, lxml, wordprocessingml

For the past few days, I have been trying to manipulate a MS Word Document through its .xml file. The main idea would be to insert bookmark controls into an existing document using Python. I know there is a library called Docx that already have a few functions for MS Word, but it does not do what I need (at least not yet), so I am working with the lxml library. This is how a bookmark is represented in a word xml file:

```
<w:p>
  <w:r>
    <w:t xml:space="preserve">This is text with a </w:t>
  </w:r>
  <w:bookmarkStart w:id="0" w:name="myAnchor"/>
  <w:r>
    <w:t>bookmark</w:t>
  </w:r>
  <w:bookmarkEnd w:id="0"/>
</w:p>
```

After some research in other posts, I have the following code:

```
def getXml(docxFilename):
    zip = zipfile.ZipFile(open(docxFilename, "rb"))
    xmlString = zip.read("word/document.xml")
    return xmlString

#Importa a string o
tmp_doc_xml = getXml("/home/davids/Documents/tmp_doc.docx")
root = etree.fromstring(tmp_doc_xml)
a = open("/home/davids/PycharmProjects/Bookmarks/root_xml", "w")

print >>a, (etree.tostring(root, pretty_print=True))

bookmarks_list = root.findall('.//' + qn('w:bookmarkStart'))
for bookmark in bookmarks_list:
    name = bookmark.get(qn('w:name'))
    print >>a, 'bookmark: '+ str(bookmark) + '\n' + 'content: ' + (etree.tostring(bookmark, pretty_print=True))

bookmarks_list = root.findall('.//' + qn('w:bookmarkEnd'))
for bookmark in bookmarks_list:
    name = bookmark.get(qn('w:name'))
    print >>a, 'bookmark: '+ str(bookmark) + '\n' + 'content: ' + (etree.tostring(bookmark, pretty_print=True))
```

I would like to highlight that some of the content of this code was not created by me, instead it is a compilation of functions I found on internet.

Basically, it unzips the word file and saves its document.xml file as a string, then it imports this string as a tree format. So, what I am trying to do is:

a. Insert a new bookmark to the existing xml code

b. Show the content in a bookmark (That is, the content between bookmarkStart and bookmarkEnd for the same id number)

Thanks,
David

Comment: Of course I tried googling the issue. And of course I have seen this link before. If it had solved my problem, I wouldn't be here.

Comment: You may want to apply the advice in http://biblehub.com/matthew/7-3.htm (or in Hebrew https://www.safa-ivrit.org/exp-abc/tet/%D7%98%D7%95%D7%9C+%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94+%D7%9E%D7%91%D7%99%D7%9F+%D7%A2%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%9A),  but as you asked so politely and kindly ... I deleted my comments.